# VK API: Рассылка сообщений через бота (или ВК API)

Tags: vkontakte-api

Задача состоит в том, что бы сделать простой скрипт с рассылкой сообщений участникам сообщества. Для этого я использую токен группы.

У ВК есть одно неприятное ограничение: нельзя отправлять сообщения пользователям от имени сообщества, пока пользователь не напишет первым, или не нажмёт кнопку "разрешить сообщения".

Сейчас я реализовал скрипт где вытягиваю всех участников группы и рассылаю им сообщения. Функцию рассылки я обернул в try catch, поскольку выбрасывается исключение если пользователю нельзя писать от имени сообщества. Для этих целей использую API метод "groups.getMemebers", но из всех участников мне нужны только те, которым можно писать. В объектах списка пользователей свойства не нашёл, фильтрации с таким условием в методе нет и другой метод не могу найти.

Вопрос, существует ли такой метод, или свойство в объекте пользователя и где смотреть, как называется?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам поможет метод [messages.isMessagesFromGroupAllowed](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.isMessagesFromGroupAllowed)